# How to send a custom push notification using parse .NET

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I'm trying to send a push notification using C#(Windows Forms) and i did it and what i want is send a notification to a channel that users have inscribed.
Her's my code using C# to send a simple notification for all users

```
var parsePush = new ParsePush();

        parsePush.Data = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"alert", TxtOne.Text},// this is replacement for parsePush.Alert
        };
        await parsePush.SendAsync();
```

Comment: Please explain what isn't working and what you've done to troubleshoot.

Comment: thanks, i find out how to solve this issue!